# Fourier transform of a multivariate gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-analysis

What is the Fourier transform of the following function:
$$
    f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{P} \mathbf{x}}
$$

I know the solution for the one-dimensional problem, and I can find the solution for $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{I}$, but I don't know how to handle a general positive-definite $\mathbf{P}$.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbf P$ symmetric  positive definite, $\mathbf P=\mathbf Q^T\,\mathbf D\,\mathbf Q$ where $\mathbf D$ is diagonal and $\mathbf Q$ is orthogonal. Then
$$
\mathbf{x}^T\, \mathbf{P}\, \mathbf{x}=(\mathbf{Q}\,\mathbf{x})^T\,D\,(\mathbf{Q}\,\mathbf{x}).
$$
Make the change of variables $\mathbf y=\mathbf{Q}\,\mathbf{x}$, and take into account that since $\mathbf Q$ is orthogonal
$$
\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf\xi=\mathbf y\cdot(\mathbf Q\,\mathbf\xi).
$$

Comment: OK, so I can define a new function $g(y) = e^{-\frac{1}{2} y^T D y}$, for which I can compute the inverse Fourier transform. But I don't want the inverse-fourier of $g$, I want the inverse-fourier of $f(x) = g(Qx)$.

Comment: You said you want to compute $\hat f$. Writing the definition and doing the change of variables $\hat f(\xi)=\hat g(\mathbf Q\cdot\xi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Cholesky of
$\frac12 \mathbf{P} = \mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^T$,
we see that
$
f(\mathbf{x})
= 
h(\mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{x})
$
where
$
h(\mathbf{x})
=e^{- \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}}
$.

Using the stretch property, it holds
$$
\hat{f}(\mathbf{k})
= 
\frac{1}{| \det(\mathbf{L}^T) |}
\hat{h}(\mathbf{L}^{-1}\mathbf{k})
=
\frac{2^{d/2}}{| \det(\mathbf{P}) |^{1/2}}
\hat{h}(\mathbf{L}^{-1}\mathbf{k})
$$

It remains to compute the FT of
$h(\mathbf{x})$.
In 1-d, we know that
the FT of $e^{-x^2}$ is
$\sqrt{\pi} e^{-k^2/4}$ from which we deduce
the multimensional FT of $h(\mathbf{x})$ is
$$
\hat{h}(\mathbf{k})
=
\pi^{d/2}
e^{-\frac14 \|\mathbf{k}\|^2}
$$

Putting pieces together
\begin{equation}
\boxed{
\hat{f}(\mathbf{k})
=
\frac{(2\pi)^{d/2}}{| \det(\mathbf{P}) |^{1/2}}
e^{-\frac12 \mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{k}}
}
\end{equation}